# Matlab regexp is there an or statement?

Tags: regex, matlab

Hey guys I am trying to find a way to display the letter `I` by itself but I keep having trouble this is what I have so far.

This is the text file that I open, tolls.txt:

```
Join Microsoft employees supporting I Inspire Youth Project and other youth causes #GivingHero: http://msft.it/6013jboz
Waze for @WindowsPhone is here: http://msft.it/6016jbp2 I
```

---

```
fid=fopen('tolls.txt');

getLine=fgetl(fid);

while ischar(getLine)

 ct='I\s';
 How=regexp(getLine,ct,'match');
 counter=counter+length(How);
 getLine=fgetl(fid);

end
```

---

My problem is since I have to incorporate any time there is an `I` I have to be able to show all the stand alone capital `I` that have no spaces after it such as in an end of a sentence and before a sentence. So in my bat variable I have bat=`I\s` but I don't know if there is a or statement I can use to also incorporate `\sI`.

Hope I was clear about the question thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Nope, I did not understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you'd need is something like:

```
ct = '(?<!\w)(I)(?!\w)';
```

Here `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` denote a negative look-behind and a negative look-ahead respectively for a character from the word character class.

More information about the same may be found [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

@RoneyMichael's solution is fine (though possibly overkill), but there is an or statement. Here is how you could look for three distinct patterns – `' I '` or `'I '` or `' I'`:

```
ct='(^I[\W]*\s)|(\sI[\W]*\s)|(\sI[\W]*$)';
How=regexp(getLine,ct,'match')
```

which returns:

```
How = 

    ' I '    ' I'
```

The last two patterns specifically match the latter `'I'` if it occurs at the beginning or the end of the string, respectively. The `'[\W]*'` matches zero or more occurrences of non-word characters, i.e., punctuation. It's zero or more because of things like '...', '?!', etc. Alternatively, you could explicitly list allowed punctuation by using something like `'[\.\?\!]*'` instead (just remember that things such as quotes, parentheses, brackets, etc. can also come at the end of a line). Also, you may want to match `'"I'` or `''I'`. In that case you can simply use

```
ct='(^[\W]*I[\W]*\s)|(\s[\W]*I[\W]*\s)|(\s[\W]*I[\W]*$)';
```

There are [other logical and conditional operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#bqv21pe-1) that you can use in regular expressions.

Comment: Hi, I'd thought about this initially, but the issue here is that it would not capture `I`s in cases such as `"Am I?"`.

Comment: @RoneyMichael: True. I think that you can just add a case for that: `'\sI\W'`. Of course that means the regex-free solution won't work.

Comment: hey I have another concern to this what if the statement said "Hello I'm james" then if I used the statement still it would give me one value match for I? since "I'm" would be considered to be the case when it is ' I' I just want the I value when it is a stand alone value.

Comment: @user3068363: Do you want to match `I'm` or not match it? It's not an `'I'` by itself so these patterns don't match it.

Comment: No I do not want to match it I figured it would match it since it follows the rule of ' I'

Comment: Because there is an `'m'` rather than a space or an end of line (`'$'`) after the apostrophe, `'I'm'` actually doesn't completely match any of the patterns.